# Como utilizar a classe COM do PHP para acessar funções da dll do emulador SAT sefaz?

Tags: php, dll, erp

Estou desenvolvendo um `ERP` que precisa utilizar `SAT` para emissão de Cupom Fiscal Eletrônico, porém não sei como utilizar o `PHP` para acessar a `DLL` do Emulador Offline.

Estive pesquisando e parece que é possível aceder com `new COM()`, mas vi pouco conteúdo referente a isso.

Alguém com conhecimento para dar um help?

Comment: O `new COM` só libera as funções das DLLs ou porta (depende do que você vai fazer), mas basicamente o que você precisa é da documentação das tais DLLs e que elas possuam um "activex" (servidor COM...???) para saber os comandos e não do PHP necessariamente.

Comment: Na verdade eu preciso acessar as funções desta DLL. Eu tenho o manual com as funções que a dll do SAT oferece, porém não estou conseguindo acessar a dll. Tento acessar com a classe com passando nome da DLL (new COM(nome_da_dl.dl)) mas retorna o erro Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'com_exception' with message 'Failed to create COM object'

Comment: A dll tá registrada (com `REGSVR32`)? Note que conforme a documentação do PHP, se a DLL não tiver suporte para de servidor COM ou `IDispatch` então o PHP não vai poder fazer nada, o PHP não acessa DLLs, ele acessa o COM da DLL.

Comment: Diego isso `new COM(nome_da_dl.dl)` não tem sentido, o COM é para acessar DLLs registradas, tem certeza que leu mesmo a doc do php? Vou passar o link e tentar formular uma resposta, segue link da doc: http://php.net/manual/en/faq.com.php

Comment: Obrigado pelas respostas Guilherme. A dll não é registrada, é fornecida pelo Sefaz e não sei informar se ela tem suporte COM ou IDispatch, no manual não há referência a isso. O problema é a inexistência de exemplos e documentação para acessar as funções para comunicar com o Emulador SAT no PHP. Estou a 2 dias pesquisando e nada :(.

Comment: O PHP não tem como documentar nada disto, o que ele faz é liberar acesso ao funções, veja se consegue entender a resposta que postei e tente usar o `new COM` e depois me informa o erro/exception que ocorre exatamente

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para usar a classe `COM` é necessário ativar a extensão `php_com_dotnet.dll` no php.ini (claramente isto é somente para Windows), algo assim:

```
extension=php_com_dotnet.dll
```

Após isto é necessário reiniciar o Apache/Nginx/lighttpd (ou reiniciar o servidor/máquina).

- A classe `new COM` não tem muita documentação mesmo, porque não tem o que falar, isto porque a única coisa que ele faz é liberar as funções de uma *DLL registrada* no sistema operacional.
- A classe não carrega ou lê DLLs, ela apenas carrega as funções de DLLs registradas, como exemplo de uso de alguns ActiveX.
- COM significa *Component Object Model*, ou seja a classe só irá acessar DLLs que usam coisas como OLE, basicamente se a DLL não for feita com OLE e compatíveis, não será possivel usar `new COM`, pois como disse isso não é uma classe para carregar DLLs e sim para carregar as funções de DLLs registradas no Sistema.

  > eu não sei afirmar se é possível acessar todos ActiveX, COM+ e DCOM, que são outras tecnologias do mesmo seguimento, irei editar a resposta assim que puder confirmar.

Para se registrar uma DLLs é necessário eventualmente rodar o comando [REGSVR32](https://technet.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/bb490985.aspx):

```
REGSVR32 minhadll.dll
```

Se a DLL tiver a interface COM e o registro ocorrer tudo bem, então você terá acesso via PHP normalmente, algo como (exemplo hipotético):

- Registrar:

  ```
  REGSVR32 FooBar.dll
  ```
- Usar:

  ```
  $my_dll = new COM('FooBar.Functions');
  ```

### Executar DLL por linha de comando

Supondo que a documentação forneça algum acesso a uma ferramenta de linha de comando do proprio SAT, poderia usar um `shell_exec` assim:

```
$comando = escapeshellcmd('ferramenta_sat_hipotetica.exe comando1 comando2 arg3');
$resposta = shell_exec($comando);

echo $resposta;
```

Você pode tentar também rodar o comando RUNDLL32 do windows:

```
RUNDLL32.EXE <dllname>,<entrypoint> <optional arguments>
```

Ficaria algo como:

```
RUNDLL32.EXE MINHADLL.DLL,Install 200 Argumento
```

No PHP ficaria assim:

```
$comando = escapeshellcmd('RUNDLL.EXE MINHADLL.DLL,Install 200 Argumento');
$resposta = shell_exec($comando);

echo $resposta;
```

Leia mais sobre o RUNDLL em:

- https://technet.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/ee649171(v=ws.10).aspx
- https://support.microsoft.com/pt-br/kb/164787

Encontrei a documentação e um exemplo com a DLL, no exemplo eles colocaram um aspas a mais, talvez seja erro de digitação `new COM('"SATscript.DLL.object')`, todavia se falhar tente isto `new COM('SATscript.DLL.object')`.

Primeiro baixe o http://sistemas.sweda.com.br/downloads/suporte/SATscript.zip depois rode o `REGSATscript.exe` que esta dentro do compacto, ele vai registrar a DLL, deve rodar a versão 64bit se você estiver usando Windows 64bit, qualquer duvida ou problema dentro da pasta tem este arquivo `SATscript.zip\Manual\ManualdoUsuarioSATScript.pdf`, depois de registrar a DLL basta executar:

```
<?php

try {
    $SATsw = new COM('"SATscript.DLL.object') OR die ('NÃO POSSO CRIAR OBJETO');

    // "?????????????????    S T A T U S   ???????????????????????????"
    // "Índice       Retorno 0                     Retorno 1 "
    // "  1    Impressora operacional        Impressora em falha" 
    // "  2    Off Line                      On Line "
    // "  3    Papel OK                      Fim de papel "
    // "  4    Guilhotina não detectada      Guilhotina detectada "
    // "  5    Tampa térmica fechada         Tampa térmica aberta "
    // "  6    Sem papel sobre o sensor      Papel posicionado sobre o sensor "
    // "  7    Gaveta fechada                Gaveta aberta. "
    // "  8    Cheque inserido               SEM CHEQUE."

    $LF = '<br>';

    $retorno = $SATsw->Status_SI300 ("1");  
    echo 'Status_SAT ("1")   ->  Operacional?    = ', $retorno, $LF;

    $retorno = $SATsw->Status_SI300 ("2");  
    echo 'Status_SAT ("2")   ->  ON/OFF?         = ', $retorno, $LF;

    $retorno = $SATsw->Status_SI300 ("3");  
    echo 'Status_SAT ("3")   ->  FIM Papel?      = ', $retorno, $LF;

    $retorno = $SATsw->Status_SI300 ("4");  
    echo 'Status_SAT ("4")   ->  Guilhotina?     = ', $retorno, $LF;

    $retorno = $SATsw->Status_SI300 ("5");  
    echo 'Status_SAT ("5")   ->  Tampa?          = ', $retorno, $LF;

    $retorno = $SATsw->Status_SI300 ("6");  
    echo 'Status_SAT ("6")   ->  Papel acabando? = ', $retorno, $LF;

    $retorno = $SATsw->Status_SI300 ("7");  
    echo 'Status_SAT ("7")   ->  Gaveta?         = ', $retorno, $LF;

    $retorno = $SATsw->Status_SI300 ("8");  
    echo 'Status_SAT ("8")   ->  Cheque?         = ', $retorno, $LF;

    $retorno = $SATsw->StatusGuilhotina_SI300 ();
    echo 'StatusGuilhotina_SI300 () -> Guilhotina? = ', $retorno, $LF;

} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo 'resultado: ', $e->getMessage(), "\n";
}
```

Comment: Obrigado Guilherme, vou procurar outra forma, pois a dll não é 'registrável', mas sua resposta já me fará tentar outro caminho, pois ainda não sei qual método utilizar para comunicar com este emulador SAT no PHP.

Comment: @DiegoQueiroz fora as DLLs, esse SAT tem linha de comando? Porque se tiver já tenho uma resposta :)

Comment: @DiegoQueiroz editei a resposta, veja se o exemplo lhe serve, note que o tal SAT deve ter uma doc que venha a prover exemplos de uso para em seguida tentar o RUNDLL ou a tal ferramenta que citei.

Comment: @GilhermeNascim consegui comunicar com o aplicativo emulador do SAT dessa forma que falou, obrigado. Ainda não estou conseguindo passar os parâmetros da função corretamente. A função é EnviarDadosVenda e ela espera 3 parametros. Tentei passar assim $comando = `RUNDLL32.EXE dllsat.dll, EnviarDadosVenda 012346 12345678 xml`. Como passo os parâmetros?

Comment: @DiegoQueiroz acho que tá sobrando um espaço depois da virgula `dllsat.dll, EnviarDadosVenda`, seria assim `dllsat.dll,EnviarDadosVenda`, os argumentos só tendo a documentação da dll e realmente eu não achei na net nada sobre dllsat.dll :/

Comment: @GuilermeNascimento eu testei com a RUNDLL32.exe, foi possível comunicar com o emulador SAT, mas não foi possível passar os parâmetros corretamente. Talvez essa dll não seja preparada para isso, não sei dizer, pois sou leigo nessa parte. Enfim, acabei indo por outro caminho utilizando um programa que utiliza sockets e faz a intermediação entre o meu programa e o emulador SAT. Obrigado pela ajuda!

Comment: @DiegoQueiroz isso do socket foi massa, formula uma resposta depois ;)

Comment: @DiegoQueiroz consegui encontrar no site o manual e a ferramenta para registrar a DLL, editei a resposta e coloquei um exemplo

Comment: @GuilermeNascimento ainda não tive tempo de testar essa solução que vc encontrou. Vou pegar um tempinho hoje no final da tarde e te dou resposta. Vlw!

Comment: @GuilermeNascimento testei essa solução do SATScript, mas ela só funciona nos SAts da marca SWEDA pelo que pude ver. Como terei varias marcas de SAT de gosto do cliente a unica solução que achei por enquanto foi mesmo a utilização do ACBR Monitor PLUS. Vlw!